# Server side errors handling with angular-formly

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I'm looking for solution on how I can display errors that the server respond, this is the respond for every invalid submission so I want to make the error handler in the app level and not in a controller.
I want to display the errors both on the FORM level and on the field level.

I have a REST API that in case of error return the following JSON object:

```
{
  "message": "Validation error: Validation notEmpty failed,\nValidation error: Validation isEmail failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "field": "username",
      "message": "Validation notEmpty failed"
    },
    {
      "field": "email",
      "message": "Validation isEmail failed"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I create a service that display the errors in case there is any?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i created this for another answer. Let me know if this sort of a setup works for you. Here, the error is intended to be displayed on response from the server after button click. You can modify it accordingly.

I have given the field a custom template as follows:

```
 formlyConfigProvider.setWrapper({
      name: 'inputWrapper',
  template: '<div ng-class="to.changeColor==\'red\'? \'redBorder\' : \'otherBorder\'"><formly-transclude></formly-transclude>{{to.keyVal}}</div>'
    });
```

The form elements are defined through a schema format to allow each element to be individually accessed.

```
vm.schema={
    "schema": {
        "coolValue" : [{
                "key": "coolValue",
                "type": "input",

          "wrapper": ['inputWrapper'],
                "templateOptions": {
                   "type" : "text",
                  "label": 'Cool Value',
                  "keyVal":"",
                  "changeColor":"green"
                }

         }]


    }

};
```

Finally, the `onSubmit` function

```
function onSubmit() {

//Do whatever you want here
//Let's say your server returns an error "iNVALID Credentials"
   var response={
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization",
      }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid Credentials"
  }
};
vm.schema.schema.coolValue[0].templateOptions.changeColor="red";
      vm.schema.schema.coolValue[0].templateOptions.keyVal=response.error.message;

    }
  });
```

You can essentially pass any error message or response from the server here.

The CSS contains a class to add a red `border` to the field.You are free to disable this.Feel free to ping  if you need anything in this area as well.

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/bukimuwoda/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Hey Satej, Thank you for your answer.

I can't understand why I need to create a custom field wrapper and can't use the existing one. <div ng-messages="fc.$error" ng-show="showError" class="md-input-messages-animation ng-inactive ng-hide" aria-live="assertive" aria-hidden="true">

Comment: Hi @Asaf, I've come across multiple examples and they've gone the custom route, including ones on the official [doc](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/other/toggle-required). Additionally, i tried the approach in your comment, and haven't really been successful setting the fc.$error explicity as opposed to it being set in validation.