# using angular-formly for form validations, the validation error messages are not shown when clicking submit

Tags: angular-formly

The issue is a validation messages appears and the textfield turns red when specific fields are clicked and blurred out. But when I click the submit button of the form without touching any of the input fields, no error messages are shown and none of the textfields turn red.

The correct way is, it has to show all the validation messages during the submission and all the textfields have to turn red.

The plunk for this is

http://plnkr.co/edit/fNUdp7Qdd0ysrd0eiPFT

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Angular-Formly</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>

<!-- form declaration-->
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as vm">
    <div class="container col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <form novalidate name="vm.form"  ng-submit="vm.formsubmit()" >
         <formly-form model="vm.user" fields="vm.fields" form="vm.form" >

         </formly-form>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
       </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Application Dependencies -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/api-check/7.2.4/api-check.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-messages@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-formly/6.11.0/formly.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap/4.3.1/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap.js"></script>


    <!-- Application Scripts -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="MainController.js"></script>


    <script type="text/ng-template" id="custom-messages.html">
    <div class="my-messages" ng-messages="field.$error" ng-style="{color: 'red'}" ng-if="form.$submitted">
        <div  class="my-message" ng-message"required">required Message</div>
    </div>
    </script> 


    <script type="text/ng-template" id="formly-messages.html">
    <formly-transclude></formly-transclude>
    <div class="my-messages" ng-messages="form.$error" ng-style="{color: 'red'}" ng-if="fc.$touched">
        <div ng-repeat="(name, message) in ::options.validation.messages" ng-message="{{::name}}">{{message(fc.$viewValue, fc.$modelValue, this)}}
        </div>
    </div>
    </script> 
  </body>

</html>
```

Can anyone kindly give me the solution for this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if this will help in any way, but have a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/37153508/4759033

Answer (score 0):

It seems the form won't allow you to submit it, because you've got required fields in there.

Therefore the `form.$submitted` value will never be true in your option setting `formlyConfigProvider.extras.errorExistsAndShouldBeVisibleExpression`.